# SQL-How to get sum column in the last column of each sum columns

Tags: sql

I am using user Keevas' example, but asking a different question....

```
select Master_Code, SUM(Jan), SUM(Feb), SUM(Mar)
 from dbo.foobar
WHERE Participating_City = 'foofoo'
GROUP BY Master_Code ORDER BY Master_Code ASC
```

something like this:

```
Master_Code sum(Jan) Sum(Feb) sum(Mar)  Total
        1     4         5       4        13
        2     5         5       5        15
```

How do I get Total value column? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select Master_Code, 
       SUM(Jan), 
       SUM(Feb),
       SUM(Mar),
       SUM(Jan+Feb+Mar) as Total
from dbo.foobar
WHERE Participating_City = 'foofoo'
GROUP BY Master_Code
ORDER BY Master_Code ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select Master_Code
    , SUM(Jan)
    , SUM(Feb)
    , SUM(Mar)
    , (SUM(Jan + Feb + Mar)) As Total
 from dbo.foobar
WHERE Participating_City = 'foofoo'
GROUP BY Master_Code 
ORDER BY Master_Code ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add them using plus sign.

```
SELECT Master_Code, SUM(Jan), SUM(Feb), SUM(Mar), SUM(Jan) + SUM(Feb) + SUM(Mar) FROM...
```